# How can I create a week group column in my Date Dimension Table based on this specific logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table in my Database called Date Dimension.

It has a column called "Date" which contains daily dates from 01 January 2013 to 31 December 2025 (extract of the column given below):

```
Date
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
2022-01-04
2022-01-05
2022-01-06
2022-01-07
2022-01-09
...
2022-01-30
2022-01-31
...
```

I need to create a new column in the Date Dimension Table called "HR_WeekGroup" based on the following logic:

A WeekGroup will start on a Monday and end on a Sunday. WeekGroups will be calculated for EACH Month separately. That is, if the 1st Day of a Month is a Saturday, the WeekGroup for that week will consist of only 2 days (Saturday and Sunday) and if the last Day of that Month is a Monday, the weekGroup will consist of only 1 Day (Monday).

Here is what I'm after (based on the Month of January 2022):

```
   Date          HR_WeekGroup
2022-01-01       Wk 01Jan2022-02Jan2022
2022-01-02       Wk 01Jan2022-02Jan2022
2022-01-03       Wk 03Jan2022-09Jan2022
2022-01-04       Wk 03Jan2022-09Jan2022
2022-01-05       Wk 03Jan2022-09Jan2022
2022-01-06       Wk 03Jan2022-09Jan2022
2022-01-07       Wk 03Jan2022-09Jan2022
2022-01-09       Wk 03Jan2022-09Jan2022
...              ...
2022-01-30       Wk 24Jan2022-30Jan2022
2022-01-31       Wk 31Jan2022
...
```

What would be the T-SQL Code that would allow me to create this column?

I had a look at the following pages but I can't figure out how to apply the examples to my specific problem.

[What is the SQL syntax to create a column in my Date Dimension Table that will group the dates into this specific week grouping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735797/what-is-the-sql-syntax-to-create-a-column-in-my-date-dimension-table-that-will-g)

[How to Group Data by Week in SQL Server](https://learnsql.com/blog/group-data-sql-server/)

Answer (score 3):

```
Set DateFirst 1;
-- The above changes the start of the week to Monday.
-- This makes the week as starting on Monday and ending on Sunday
-- DayOfWeek 1 means Monday
-- DayOfWeek 7 means Sunday
with cte as (
    select 
        Date_Column, 
        MONTH(Date_Column) as [MONTH],  -- Month in the year
        DAY(Date_Column) as [DAY], -- Day in the month
        DATEPART(week,Date_Column) as [WeekOfTheYear], --Week number of the year
        DATEPART(dw,Date_Column) as [DayOfWeek], -- The week day of the week
        Min(Date_Column) OVER (Partition by DATEPART(week,Date_Column), MONTH(Date_Column), YEAR(Date_Column) ) as [MinDateWeekGroup],
        Max(Date_Column) OVER (Partition by DATEPART(week,Date_Column), MONTH(Date_Column), YEAR(Date_Column) ) as [MaxDateWeekGroup]
    from date_dimension
    --order by YEAR(Date_Column), MONTH(Date_Column), DAY(Date_Column)  
)
select 
    Date_Column,
    case when [MinDateWeekGroup] = [MaxDateWeekGroup] 
        THEN CONCAT('Wk ',
    Right('0'+Convert(varchar(10), Day([MinDateWeekGroup])),2),
    Convert(char(3), [MinDateWeekGroup], 0),Convert(char(4),YEAR([MinDateWeekGroup])) )
        ELSE 
    CONCAT('Wk ',
    Right('0'+Convert(varchar(10), Day([MinDateWeekGroup])),2),
    Convert(char(3), [MinDateWeekGroup], 0),Convert(char(4),YEAR([MinDateWeekGroup])),
    '-',
    Right('0'+Convert(varchar(10), Day([MaxDateWeekGroup])),2),
    Convert(char(3), [MaxDateWeekGroup], 0),Convert(char(4),YEAR([MaxDateWeekGroup]))
    ) 
    END as [HR_WeekGroup]
from cte
order by YEAR(Date_Column), MONTH(Date_Column), DAY(Date_Column)
```

Comment: It needs to be revised if it needs to work for periods longer than a year.

Comment: Updated the query to work for longer than an year range.

Comment: @TejaGoudKandula Thanks but I am not getting the expected result when running your solution. Example: For 2022-01-31, it is giving me a Week Group of "Wk 31Jan2000-31Jan2023" !

Comment: Please check this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6004fdc8f90b1e61bce75977e324bb9b. The output is as expected in the question.

Comment: @TejaGoudKandula Yes, your SQL Fiddle works but I am going crazy as to why it is not working on my DateDimension Table. The latter has a minimum date of 2000-01-01 and maximum date of 2023-12-31. What I have noticed if I run your cte separately from the solution, it is giving me Year 2000 in the lower end of the WeekGroup and Year 2023 as the upper end (for ALL the dates in the DateDimension Table).

Comment: Inside a cte order by clause doesn't work. I have added an order by clause, but commented it. When you are running the code inside the cte alone, uncomment it and check. The order of the dates can be sorted by using order by clause. That's it.

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. It can be tweaked to shift the starting day to Monday and/or the range to `0` through `6` as needed.